# Generic Type Parameters in functions

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I have written a generic method for writing the contents of a dictionary to an Excel Worksheet.  Generics work quite nicely, because the Excel Range Object is `dynamic`, and it therefore seamlessly handles whichever basic data type I throw into the dictionary.

In doing this, I noticed something that was unexpected to me in how the function gets called.  I wanted to ask here whether there was a preferred way of handling this.

Here is the function:

```
private void WriteDictionary<T,U>(Excel.Range startCell, int keyColumnOffset, int valueColumnOffset, Dictionary<T,U> dictionary)
{
    int row = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<T, U> value in dictionary)
    {
        startCell.Offset[row, keyColumnOffset].Value = value.Key;
        startCell.Offset[row, valueColumnOffset].Value = value.Value;
        row++;
    }
}
```

It works fine.  The thing that surprised me was the way in which the function can be called.  I expected that I would need to call it using something like this (i.e. providing the type parameters in the function call):

```
WriteDictionary<DateTime, double>(outputTemplate.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"], 0, 1, myForecastDictionary);
```

But I found that I can actually call it like this:

```
WriteDictionary(outputTemplate.Worksheets[1].Range["A2"], 0, 1, myForecastDictionary);
```

Obviously it can infer the required type parameters from the type parameters in the dictionary.  I guess that when I think about it, it isn't that surprising that the compiler can do this.

My question is this:  Is it better / more efficient (under the hood) to call the function by directly providing the types?  Or does the compiler essentially work that out at compile time, and actually generate the same code?

Comment: "Or does the compiler essentially work that out at compile time, and actually generate the same code?"  This.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods):

> The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a constraint or return value. Therefore type inference does not work with methods that have no parameters. **Type inference occurs at compile time** before the compiler tries to resolve overloaded method signatures. The compiler applies type inference logic to all generic methods that share the same name. In the overload resolution step, the compiler includes only those generic methods on which type inference succeeded.

So, it will be the same.